# Cannot pass 'S' parameter more than two letters

Tags: search

This is work:
http://localhost:8888/all-games?s=me

This doesn't work (page cannot be found):
http://localhost:8888/all-games?s=met

the post title is: Metal Gear Solid

here is my query:

```
                $args = array("posts_per_page" => get_option("posts_per_page"), "post_type" => "astro_game", "paged" => get_query_var("paged"), "s" => $_GET["s"]);
                $wp_query = new wp_query($args);
                if ($wp_query -> have_posts()) :
                    /* Start the Loop */
                    while ($wp_query -> have_posts()) : $wp_query -> the_post();                         
                        get_template_part('template-parts/content-grid', get_post_format());
                    endwhile;
                else :
                    get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'none');
                endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [**`get_query_var`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) instead of `$_GET["s"]`, this is a built-in wordpress function that retrieves **public** query variables which would have already been parsed and fed into WP_Query.

```
$args = array("posts_per_page" => get_option("posts_per_page"), "post_type" => "astro_game", "paged" => get_query_var("paged"), "s" => get_query_var("s");
```

**Reference: [WordPress_Query_Vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars#Query_variables)**

Answer (score 0):

change 's' parameter into something else, like "search", example:

http://localhost:8888/all-games?search=metal

and change wp_query args:

```
$args = array("posts_per_page" => get_option("posts_per_page"), "post_type" => "astro_game", "paged" => get_query_var("paged"), "s" => $_GET["search"]);
```

and this will work